# Can the effects of [[likely]] and [[unlikely]] be transitive/inferred?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++20

C++20 introduced the attributes `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` for signalling statements that may be either likely or unlikely executed to help with optimizations. Historically, such attributes were compiler-specific, and were hidden behind `__likely` and `__unlikely` macro function to help optimize branching statements; however C++20 takes this a step further by allowing them on *any* statements.

In theory, this should allow for `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` inference, based on context and visibility -- such as:

```cpp
// Just an opaque function to call so we see it in the generated assembly
void something_expensive();

// Something we know to always be unlikely
[[gnu::always_inline]]
inline void unlikely_code_path() {
    [[unlikely]] something_expensive();
}

void test_unlikely(bool x) {
    if (x) /* [[unlikely]] inferred? */ { unlikely_code_path(); }
}
```

I use an `inline`d/visible function-call in this example since I can see this being useful for error-managing functions like `assert`, which are never *meant* to be tripped in practice and thus we don't want paths leading to these cases to be optimized for. However, I'm not seeing any compiler actually take advantage of this.

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/e1zfzfGGG)</kbd>

Both GCC and Clang are generating identical assembly outputs, neither of which take advantage of the `[[unlikely]]` (or `[[likely]]`) knowledge:

```
test_unlikely(bool):
        test    dil, dil
        je      .L4
        jmp     something_expensive()
.L4:
        ret
```

My expectation is that `test_unlikely` would be aware of the `[[unlikely]]` branch and generate something similar to what would be generated if this were `if (b) [[unlikely]] { ...}`, which is:

```
test_unlikely(bool):
        test    dil, dil
        jne     .L6
        ret
.L6:
        jmp     something_expensive()
```

Is this a missed opportunity for compilers to label the "hot" and likely paths? Or is there something I am missing about the C++ language that may actually prevent such optimizations from being realistic using attributes alone in practice?

(**Note:** I know that attributes in C++ are effectively non-binding contracts, and thus the compiler does not *need* to honor them; but the compilers here clearly *are* honoring *some* cases which makes me think this is just a missed optimization)

Comment: These attributes don't impact behavior, so under the as-if rule they can optimize or not optimize according to them as they wish. C++20 is very recent, compiler developers probably haven't had time to take advantage of it yet. They'll priorities mandatory features and changes to become compliant before worrying about these nice-to-haves.

Comment: Most modern amd64 processors generally don't rely on static hints anymore. So you're unlikely to see differences in trivial examples like these. Where it may make a difference is in large/complex functions: then the unlikely parts are pushed away from the likely ones to e.g. maximize icache locality and minimize page faults.

Comment: I really doubt that it was the intent.